# Angular 7 Form Validation and Display error message

Tags: angular, angular6, angular7, angular4-forms

Please look my simple form in Stackblitz

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-et9uww

My form contains 2 checkboxes if I select one of the checkboxes it will populate one textbox. In my scenario, I have 2 checkboxes and 2 text boxes and one submit button.

NOTE- in my case i have n number of checkbox and child questions

Validation includes -> 2 textbox are mandatory

If the user submits the form without entering textbox it will show the error message.

### STEP to Recreate

1. check the checkbox1, textbox will appear without any error message

[screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OEnvA.png)

2.then submit the form it will show the error. that is fine.

[screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zZRIp.png)

3. check the checkbox2, again new textbox will appear with error message without clicking submit button.

[screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QBca7.png)

[screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hTvFr.png)

But I WANT that second error message display only if the user hit submit button again.

Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure I get what your question is. You chose to display the error message if the form has been submitted: `|| angularForm.submitted`. So, since the form has been submitted, the error message is displayed. If you don't want that, then don't show the error message when the form has been submitted.

Comment: What the questions is?

Comment: i want to show the error message only if the field is invalid while submit the form 2nd time. but in my case error is displaying while populating the textbox. how to handle this case. please check the application in stackblitz  STEP to Recreate

Comment: STEP to Recreate  1. check the checkbox1, textbox will appear without any error message, then submit the form it will show the error. that is fine. 2. check the checkbox2, again new textbox will appear with error message. But I WANT that second error message display only if the user hit submit button in second time.

Comment: please try this in stackblitz

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I got your point, but try this:

add some variable submitCount: number to your component; then everytime you click the submit button, just increase this counter; and finally add to the ngIf of your 2nd textbox 'submitCount > 1 &&' and this should be it?

Comment: please check my prototype in stackblitz https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-et9uww. my question is I have to validate only available fields in the form not for upcoming field. In my scenario all fields are validated at one submit.

Comment: STEP to Recreate

check the checkbox1, textbox will appear without any error message, then submit the form it will show the error. that is fine.

check the checkbox2, again new textbox will appear with error message. But I WANT that second error message display only if the user hit submit button in second time.