# Angular 7 Event Binding

Tags: angular, angular6, angular7

Can you please tell me to Toggle Show and Hide div content using button click event without using variable and event binding. Sample code

```
<form>
   <div *ngIf="--CAPTURE BUTTON CLICK EVENT HERE--">
     <span>Welcome</span>
   </div>
   <button type="submit">Click Me</button>
</form>
```

Please suggest me the solution How to listen button click event in *ngIf.

Comment: what do you need that for?

Comment: not clear what you're asking at all... click binding syntax is basic angular, read the docs if not familiar. If there's some reason you think standard event binding won't work, make it clear why and what you're trying to accomplish

Comment: I'm not really sure what you want to achieve here, you only want the button to be displayed while the user is clicking in the button ? If not why don't you use a variable that changes value when the user clicks the button?

Comment: TO achieve this question  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57315314/angular-7-form-validation-and-display-error-message

Answer (score 0):

You can do by this

```
<form>
   <div *ngIf="state">
     <span>Welcome</span>
   </div>
   <button type="submit" (click)=state = !state>Click Me</button>
</form>
```

Comment: First I think you forgot to add "..."  after the action definition of the click event. Second, the user clearly asked that no variable can be used.

Comment: @piotrszybicki  i understand what user said but the answer was assuming for achieving the outcome, as its not clearly mention why he was doing it.

Comment: to solve this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57315314/angular-7-form-validation-and-display-error-message